# Recursive instance definitions

Tags: haskell

I have a recursive data definitions:

```
data Checked a =  forall b. Checked (Either (Warning, Maybe (Checked b), a) a)
```

I need to define Show recursively:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Checked a) where
  show (Right v) = show v
  show (Left (w, Nothing, v) = show w ++ show v
  show (Left (w, Just ch, v) = show w ++ show v ++ "caused by" ++ show ch --recursive here
```

GHC gives

```
 Could not deduce (Show b) arising from a use of `show'
  from the context (Show a)
  bound by the instance declaration at Checked.hs:29:10-35
  Possible fix:
   add (Show b) to the context of
    the data constructor `Checked'
    or the instance declaration
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show ch'
```

If I add (Show b) to the constraints on the instance definition, GHC gives:

```
 Ambiguous constraint `Show b'
  At least one of the forall'd type variables mentioned by the constraint
  must be reachable from the type after the '=>'
In the instance declaration for `Show (Checked a)'
```

Is there a next step I should take to get this to compile?

Comment: Please notice that @HaskellElephant has corrected your code (which should really be posted in an answer instead of in your question).

Comment: @AndrewC I thought that the error had nothing to with the question asked so I corrected it. Should I revert it? The fix is covered by Sjoerd Visschers answer.

Comment: @HaskellElephant. I nearly reverted it myself, but wanted to give you the opportunity to put your edit as part of an answer. If you revert it, add a line in Sjoerd's answer to explain that `Checked` should be there. (It's unclear whether Sjoerd saw the original or the edited version.) I think it's OK to edit trivial obvious mistakes in an answer, but if you edit the question without telling the asker, they might not notice and they'll be left in the dark unnecessarily. If you do revert it, please reply to me again so I can delete my comments.

Comment: @AndrewC well, one thing is what the asker thinks but anyone visiting this post again to find out what the question is about will have a hard time with the extra errors. Note that it is not just the extra `Checked` there is a mismatched parenthesis a missing `where`, and a wrong indentation which will give you a parse error before you get to the error in the question. I'll revert the edit and make it an answer instead.

Comment: Sorry folks. Corrected those sloppy errors myself. Put it down to unfamiliarity with the wonderful stackoverflow

Comment: Notice that @HaskellElephant made more corrections than that - look at revision 2 in the edit history (click on the time after the word edited). If you prefer to ask that version of the question, it would be worth rolling back to HaskellElephant's version, and I've just wasted people's time with my pedantic adherance to my perception of SO best practice. Sorry.

Comment: @RobertOnslow seems like there is yet another mismatched parenthesis now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `Show b` restriction to the data type:

```
data Checked a = forall b. Show b => Checked (Either (Warning, Maybe (Checked b), a) a)

instance Show a => Show (Checked a) where
  show (Checked (Right v)) = show v
  show (Checked (Left (w, Nothing, v))) = show w ++ show v
  show (Checked (Left (w, Just ch, v))) = show w ++ show v ++ "caused by" ++ show ch
```

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, but is there a solution in which I don't have to contaminate Checked with Show in this way? Because now the compiler is asking for Show a => constraints in other Checked instance declarations, e.g. Applicative which have nothing to do with Show

Comment: @RobertOnslow Can you manage without the existential quantification? Would `data Checked a b = ...` do? You'd be able to work without the Show context if so. Alternatively, will wrapping the whole thing in a GADT solve all your troubles?

Comment: @AndrewC I'll have a think about Checked a b first. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertOnslow You can use constraint kinds and pass a useless constraint for other cases. See my answer for usage.

Answer (score 3):

Add `Show` constraint to the data type definition.

```
data Checked a =  forall b. Show b => Checked (Either (Warning, Maybe (Checked b), a) a)
```

You can also use constraint kinds as

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Checked a c =  forall b. c b =>  Checked (Either (Maybe (Checked b c), a) a)

instance (Show a) => Show (Checked a Show) where
 show (Checked (Right v)) = show v
 show (Checked (Left (Nothing, v))) = show v
 show (Checked (Left (Just ch, v))) = show v ++ "caused by" ++ show ch
```